# Using existing lists to update the list in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, collections

I have a BaseEntity class with all my fields called ActionGame. So if I want to create a new action game I do the following:

```
var actionGame = new ActionGame
{
  price = textbox1.text,
  name = textbox2.text,
  type = textbox3.text
};
gameService.CreateUpdateActionGame(actionGame)
```

and this creates a new actiongame and with all my NHibernate mappings it saves it to the database. However, I want to update an existing action game so I don't want to create a new ActionGame as I am doing  **var actionGame = new ActionGame** what can I do instead of that? it should be similar to the way I've done the create above but not using the new because then that creates a new record

baseEntityclass:

```
public class ActionGame : BaseEntity
{
  public virtual string price { get; set; }
  public virtual string name { get; set; }
  public virtual string type { get; set; }

  public ActionGames()
  {
    ActionGames = new List<ActionGames>();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should load the item to update from the database, then update the item and call CreateUpdateActionGame with that object.

I don't know your load method but something like this:

```
var actionGame = gameService.GetByName("the name to update");
actionGame.price = textbox1.text;
actionGame.name = textbox2.text;
actionGame.type = textbox3.text;

gameService.CreateUpdateActionGame(actionGame);
```

Comment: Another way is to create a new instance with matching ID value to the record in the database, update the other values and use NHibernate Merge() method.